# Cannot export previous Sheet revisions to xlsx

Tags: google-drive-api

I am using the Google Drive REST Api V2 in order to backup certain files to a local drive. Using the revisions list method (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/revisions/list), I obtain an export link to xlsx or docx depending on my file type.

For example, the link looks like : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=[fileId]&revision=[revisionId]&exportFormat=xlsx

However, I am now unable to use the export link to xlsx on any revision except the latest on my Sheet. When following the link, I obtain a page saying : "Google Docs encountered an error. Please try reloading this page, or coming back to it in a few minutes."

I have tried using the export links to other types and these seem to work fine. Please note that I do not have the same issue with Google Docs when I use the docx format.

I have also noticed that the REST Api V3 does not offer a way to export previous revisions of Google Drive documents. Therefore, I am wondering if the reason it is not working anymore on V2 is because it simply cannot be done anymore or it is just a temporary failure.

Comment: I gave '&exportFormat=ods' a try to see if it preserves the formulas. Fortunately, it does! I think this will work for now. Give it a try.

Comment: It seems to have been fixed as of today for the xlsx export. Thank you for your suggestions. I'll be able to stick with my current method.

Comment: Good to hear. You can mark this as answered so community knows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround to your problem.
Use `exportFormat=csv` instead of `exportFormat=xlsx`. 
This will download the file as .csv file. Open the CSV file and save it as .xlsx.
This should work for you.

**EDIT:**

Just to close this thread, the Google Drive team has recently fixed the said issue. `&exportFormat=xlsx` is now working as intended. I gave it a try and it works!

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not an option as CSV does not preserve the formulas of my spreadsheet. It only keeps the values as of the time of export. My main concern is mostly the cease of support for exporting previous revisions as it is in V3 of the Api.

Comment: what if you use &exportFormat=ods ??    Can you try if it preserves your formula?

Comment: I've been looking for Revisions: list version in v3 too. Closest I can get is Files: export and Files: get but still export link is missing